# declared position fixed or absolute in a Block-level Elements

Tags: html, css

friends i want to know that if i declaired any div as a **position fixed/absolute** (without mentioning its width is 100% or something other value of width), then why it lost its default value? as i know its a Block-level Element that take full width of viewport so when i make it as a position fixed or absolute then why it look like **inline-block** and why it not a  accrued the full width of viewport?

```html
<style>
div{background:red; padding:20px 0;/*width:100%*/}
 div.demo{position:fixed;top:0; left:0;background:olive; 
  /*width:100%;*/}
</style>

<body>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
 <div class="demo">lorem ipsum</div>
 <div>lorem ipsum</div>
 <div>lorem ipsum</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

An element with **position: fixed;** is positioned relative to the **viewport**, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled,

if **you don't set it's width** the width of it's contents are  displayed as default width

if you **set it's width in percentage** then width is displayed in percentage corresponding to viewport.

so if you want a full width of view port to your div ,set it's width:100%; I'm added a snippet below.

```html
<style>
div{background:red; padding:20px 0;/*width:100%*/}
 div.demo{position:fixed;top:0; left:0;background:olive; 
  width:100%;}
</style>

<body>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
 <div class="demo">lorem ipsum</div>
 <div>lorem ipsum</div>
 <div>lorem ipsum</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Apart from this, you should declare position: relative for the parent (surrounding) div.

Comment: that is the point its take only its content width by default when it fall in fixed or absolute position..good reply sir

Answer (score 1):

From the [w3c wiki on absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Absolute_positioning):

> Absolutely positioned elements will shrink-wrap to fit their contents
>   unless you specify their dimensions.

Comment: I couldn't find an explicit explanation in the spec as to **why** this should be the case, so maybe it's just because "that's what the folks at w3c decided."